# Electric water heater T&P popping off

Tags: water-heater

I am having a problem with the T&P valve opening continuously, on & off. I found the T. stats where bad due to temp settings 140 degrees replaced, the expansion tank full of water replaced also replaced the T&P valve. last thing I will be checking is the water pressure regulating valve. If I open the cold water inlet to the tank open all the way, it opens quicker. what going on ?

Comment: What is the cold water pressure at the tap? Are you on city water or well water, for that matter?

Comment: A picture of the system would be helpful. It sounds like the pressure is too high.

Comment: Check that the expansion tank is inflated with appropriate pressure according to your house water supply

Answer (score 1):

You may have a shorted element that will cause water to over heat which in turn will cause the T&P to open regularly/occasionally.